# How does Vue check instantiation?

Tags: vue.js

All:

If I made Vue instance on same element twice, I wonder how does Vue check if that element has been applied before?

```
<div id="app"></div>


new Vue({el:"#app"})
new Vue({el:"#app"})
```

Comment: Who says it does? It doesn't appear to in my testing: https://jsfiddle.net/6rk0hmyn/1/

Comment: @ceejayoz  what Daniel Beck said is what I mean

Comment: it seems like the first one creates an exclusive lock on that element

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim That is also what I thought, but I just not do not have a simple way to understand the implement detail

Answer (score 3):

Vue *doesn't* check to see whether you've created multiple instances on the same DOM element; as you can see from the console messages below, both Vue instances are created, each with its own distinct data, and their `mounted()` events both fire:

```js
var instance1 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    foo: 'This is instance 1'
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("Instance 1 mounted")
  }
});

var instance2 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    foo: 'This is instance 2'
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("Instance 2 mounted")
  }
});

// Both Vue instances exist, with their data intact:
console.log(instance1._data.foo)
console.log(instance2._data.foo)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">{{foo}}</div>
```

But both instances wind up competing with each other over, causing errors.  Above, only the first instance's data is visible in the DOM. As another example, in the below snippet the `update` method for both instances fails to run at all:

```js
var instance1 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    foo: 'This is instance 1'
  },
  methods: {
    update() {
      this.foo = "Update from instance 1"
    }
  }
});

var instance2 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    foo: 'This is instance 2'
  },
  methods: {
    update() {
      this.foo = "Update from instance 2"
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div @click="update">{{foo}}</div>
</div>
```

...even though the same method works fine when there aren't duplicate instances of Vue on the element:

```js
var instance1 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    foo: 'This is instance 1'
  },
  methods: {
    update() {
      this.foo = "Update from instance 1"
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div @click="update">{{foo}}</div>
</div>
```

These problems aren't limited to DOM interactions; similar errors occur if the data changes on a timeout instead of on a click event.

#### TL;DR

The upshot here is, the precise details of what goes wrong and why aren't simple -- it's not as easy as "the second instance clobbers the first one" or "the first instance locks out the second one" -- but it *does* go wrong, so don't try to do it.   Both instances will wind up fighting over the same DOM elements and bindings, so it's not at all surprising that they end up interfering with one another.

(In general Vue isn't happy with DOM modifications it doesn't know about; the same types of issue are happening here as when people naively try to use jQuery to overwrite the DOM and then wonder why Vue can't update things anymore, except that in this case it's another instance of Vue instead of jQuery doing the interfering.)

If you need to check to see whether a DOM element already has a Vue instance attached to it, you can do so by checking for the presence of a "`__vue__`" property on the element:

```js
var hasVue = function(id) {
  if (document.getElementById(id).__vue__) {
    console.log("Has a vue instance attached")
  } else {
    console.log("No vue instance attached")
  }
}

hasVue('app');
new Vue({ el: '#app' });
hasVue('app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you  simply explain why "the update method for both instances fails to run at all"?

Comment: Well, the simple possibilities (B clobbers A, or A locks out B) are ruled out by the above experiments, so there probably *isn't* a simple explanation -- both instances are fighting over the same DOM elements and bindings, so it's not at all surprising that they end up interfering with one another.  In general Vue isn't happy with DOM modifications it doesn't know about; the same problems are happening here as when people try to use jQuery to overwrite the DOM and then wonder why Vue can't update things anymore, except that it's another instance of Vue instead of jQuery doing the interfering.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for my slowness, do you mean when there are multiple bindings on same element, Vue will do extra job to reject them all rather than choose one to bind?

Comment: No, I mean that neither instance knows the other one exists, so each may wind up inadvertently removing bindings set by the other (by, for example, replacing the DOM element to which those bindings are attached, or by overwriting one binding with another of the same name.)  Vue doesn't appear to have any code that checks to see whether you've doubly-instantiated it, so it's not deliberately doing any extra work to remove the other's bindings; but there are lots of ways for that to happen accidentally.

Comment: Thanks, but why there is no final winner if they just try to remove each other's binding

Comment: I don't know the precise cause, and to be honest don't see much point in digging through the Vue source code to figure out exactly why something that shouldn't work doesn't work.  Is there some reason you need to know the answer to that, or is it just academic curiosity at this point?

Comment: It is just because I need to know if one DOM element has already been taken

Comment: OK, I already explained how to check that in the answer above; look for `__vue__` on the element.

Comment: Yeah, get it. Thanks